# Cancel button instead of a back button in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I have a general question concerning the navigation between views.

I have a view controller 1 embeded in a navigation controller. In the nav bar, I have a button to do add data, when pushed, it goes to view controller 2 through segue Show (in Storyboard). In view controller 2, I return to view controller 1 after collecting data when I click the button save in nav bar on the right. I collect data with:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {...}
```

I would prefer instead of a back button to have a cancel button in the view controller 2 to return to view controller 1.

I feel something is wrong in my design but I dont know what.

In fact I am looking for something very similar to app clock.

Do you have any idea?

Edit: Here is the story board. you will notice the loop beween the two controller. how to do when I click save to not have a back button automatically on the first controller?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to select your UIBarButtonItem, click at show Attributes Inspector, click at Identifier and select "Cancel" from the drop-down menu.

[image]

[image]

```
@IBAction func cancelDownload(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Not the OP, but just wondering. Looking at one of my projects with views embedded in navigation controllers without an explicit UIBarButtonItem. Would it be possible to add one and change it like you say? Testing it now.

Comment: You just need to connect it to an IBAction and dismissViewController

Comment: @leonardo Thanks, but I am not sure still it will solve my problem. I have a loop between the two controllers. When I click save it return to the first controller with a back button.

Comment: I solved  my problem. It was an error design. I tried to connect the views with a  Show segue. Mistake. They should be connected with Present Modally. After that, I embedded my second view controller into a navigation controller. I added the cancel button as suggested Leonardo with the fonction cancelDownload. It works. Thanks Leonardo.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the text of the back button by adding this code to the view controller that contains it (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about something like that, but I am not sure if this is the correct answer. I just realised that my problem not here. When I click the button save to return to the view controller 1, in fact, it add a back button automatically to the right a of the nav. It is for that, I beleive my naviation between the views is not good. Yes, I could change Back to Cancel in the view controller 2, but it will not solve my problem. I don't know if it is clear, because for me it is not so clear too.

Comment: What do you mean by correct answer? It implements the functionality.

Comment: Ah okay, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I see what you mean, it's probably a design error in your project.

Comment: yes. I have a problem in the design. I feel. In the picture below, if I click Start, it will go the first view controller with a button back added in the left. It is a kind of a loop!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: I don't see any picture?

Comment: I can't! My project is not here, it is at work. I will try to assembly a simple one and post it.

Comment: 1. The views are assembled incorrectly. The embedding or segues are not setup so that they follow the right patterns.

Comment: 2. Or, more likely is that there's an issue with your code, specifically with prepareForSegue. I think you're passing data incorrectly.